# Как сделать запрос с нескольких БД sqlite3 + python

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

Есть два файла `messages.db` с одинаковой структурой. В каждой из которых есть таблица `users` с полями `userid`(TEXT), `nick`(TEXT) и `message`(INT). В них хранятся айди пользователей, ники и кол-во отправленных сообщений. Мне нужно сделать совместный запрос на выборку с двух этих баз данных, обьеденив записи поля `message` двух этих бд, и получить отсортированный по полю `message` список самых активных пользователей. Возможно ли это сделать?

```
import sqlite3
...

db = sqlite3.connect("messages.db")
sql = db.cursor()
sql.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (userid TEXT, nick TEXT, message INT)")
db.commit()
password = ""
email = ""

class Bot:

    def message_count(self, userid, nick):
        sql.execute("SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM users WHERE userid=(?)", (userid,))
        for value in sql:
            if value[0] == 0:
                sql.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (userid, nick, 1))
                db.commit()
            else:
                sql.execute("UPDATE users SET message = message+1, nick = ? WHERE userid = ?", (nick, userid))
                db.commit()

    def run(self):
        client.login(email=email, password=password)
        while True:
            messages = get_chat_messages(chatId=chatid, size=5)
            for message, authorid, author in zip(messages.content, messages.author.id, messages.author.nickname)

                if message:
                    self.message_count(authorid, author)
```

Comment: Покажите код, который уже есть. Как делаете запрос, куда складываете ответ и т.д. Так будет проще подсказать Вам, куда двигаться дальше, не делая всю работу за Вас.

Comment: У вас два файла messages.db в разных папках? Сделайте два коннекта к двум базам, в вопросе у вас только к одной

Comment: Есть две папки с ботами, каждый бот отвечает за отдельный чат, и в каждой этой папке по одному файлу messages.db. И как-то нужно сделать то, что я написал выше, если это возможно

Comment: Я вижу это только как раздельные подключения к бд, раздельные получения данных с последующим объединением уже в питоновых структурах данных. Кроссзапросы по нескольким базам возможны только из "больших" субд, типа оракла, и только если специальным образом настраивать подключение доверенных серверов